# Why is the tensorflow version I use in my notebook different from the version I use in my environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, version

I have tensorflow installed in my environment on windows subsystem for linux but I can't use it in my notebook. Indeed, here is my version:

```
(seg_env) antoi@LAPTOP-UTL8OHHO:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Covent Garden/Segmentation$ pip list | grep tensorflow

tensorflow           2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator 2.1.0
tensorflow-text      2.1.1
```

But when I try to import it I have:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-e25dcad80c44> in <module>
      1 # import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
      2 # !{sys.executable} -m pip install -q tensorflow-text
----> 3 from tensorflow_text import SentencepieceTokenizer
      4 
      5 get_ipython().system("{sys.executable} -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'")

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_text'
```

So I try to install it from the notebook and it tell me that my tensorflow version is not the one it needs:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.2,>=2.1.0 (from tensorflow-text) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow<2.2,>=2.1.0 (from tensorflow-text)
```

It's weird isn't it ? I thought I had tensorflow 2.1.0 ! So I tried to import tensorflow2:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
!{sys.executable} -c 'import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf; print(tf.__version__)'


/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/antoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
1.14.0
```

It seems I have tensorflow 1.14.0 ! So why is the tensorflow version I use in my notebook different from the version I use in my environment?

## Update: when I launch `jupyter-notebook` with my anaconda environment, it's not anaconda's

Indeed:

```
(seg_env3) antoi@LAPTOP-UTL8OHHO:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Covent Garden/Segmentation$ which jupyter
/home/antoi/.local/bin/jupyter
(seg_env3) antoi@LAPTOP-UTL8OHHO:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Covent Garden/Segmentation$ which jupyter-notebook
/home/antoi/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

I am now sure that I am not using the jupyter notebook from anaconda. How can I launch jupyter's one then?

Comment: How did you launch the workbook/set up the interpreter for it?

Comment: I think you used a different environment to launch your notebook. Try closing off your notebook session and restart it from the _segenv_ section again.

Answer (score 0):

Just now got a solution, don't know if its relevant to your case or not. The problem with notebook is that it might be loading a notebook of *python* default version. I just had a similar problem where tensorflow 2.0 was loading in my  notebook instead of tf 1.1.4. For that I had t create a new environment with the required tf version and installed jupyter from that environment local to it. On launching jupyter again from that environment it worked fine.

Comment: That might be the reason. I am now shure that when I load jupyter notebook with my anaconda environment on, it's not the one provided by anaconda that is used as the libraries are different. I was launching `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter-notebook`. Do you know what I should do to get the anaconda one?

Comment: So, what you might have to do here is, create a new environment first from scratch. Then install all the required packages in there or else you could also make a copy of your current environment using `conda create --clone currr_env --name cloned_env`. Then install jupyter using `conda install jupyter` from that environment. and launch your notebook from there. It should work then.